# How to identify cosntants of motion/ which constants of motion are independent of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, physical-constants, invariants

I was asked to identify a constant of motion which does not depend on the mass of the object whilst in contact with the surface. [image]

I found the equation of motion of the material point but I don't know how to identify/find a constant of motion independent of mass? How should I approach the problem?

equations of motion projected on axes:
[image]

the answer for "find a constant of motion which does not depend of mass while the point is in contact with the surface of the cone" is the following but I don't understand what it represents:
[image]

Comment: what does r^2 times dphi/dt represent?

Comment: I don't know what "cste" & "selon" are.

Comment: cste means constant and "selon" is french for "with respect to "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final equation of motion corresponds to the conservation of angular momentum. So $\dot{phi}$ is a first integral. Do you know how to solve the last equation for the first integral? Divide by $m$ and $sin\theta$ and then you can integrate directly to obtain $h=r^2 \dot{\phi}$ where $h$ is a constant of motion. Basically what you are looking for is $\frac{d}{dt}$(some expression)$=0$. Then when you integrate with respect to time you will have a constant on the RHS.

This was tough to write on an iPhone. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! but how do you integrate it once you divide by msintheta?

Comment: Can you get to $\ddot{\phi}/\dot{\phi} + 2\dot{r}/r = 0$?

Comment: Once you integrate this you'll get $\ln(\dot{\phi}) + 2\ln(r) = \ln(h)$ where $h$ is a constant. Which is equal to $r^2 \dot{\phi}. = h$.

Comment: thank you very much! I now know how to look for a constant of motion( look for expressions such that d/dt = 0  and integrate it  to get the expression = const !  :)

Comment: How do you know that the final equation corresponds to the conservation of angular momentum ? the answer is r*angularvelocity (m^2 /s) should it be r*angularvelocity*m to be the angular momentum?
Ahhh or is it because we divided by m at the start ?

Comment: Well this is precisely the angular momentum in the $\phi$ direction. You should convince yourself of this. The question is looking for mass independence. Be careful with your definition of angular momentum and angular velocity. These are generally very different concepts!